# How to dynamically change the line height of each line in content editable div in php jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I want to make a rich text editor for my website.I used content editable div for it. I was done maximum thing of my editor like bold italic align etc. Now I want to set several line spacing for it.When i will put the cursor in a line, then i click any specific line height from drop down menu,only the line height will be changed, no other line will be changed. I have no any idea about how to do this. So please help me. Here is the basic idea of it.
html code

```
<select>line Space
    <option>20px</option>
    <option>80px</option>
    <option>100px</option>
    <option>200px</option>
</select>
<button id="bold" onclick="document.execCommand('bold')">Bold</button>



<div id="textcontent" contenteditable ="true"></div>
```

CSS code

```
#textcontent{
  line-height=10px;

    min-height: 760px;

    padding: 50px;
    width: 650px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-height: 900px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;

    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: *"So please help me"* does not qualify as a programming question. Also the topic you're asking help for is quite broad, I can't see how it can be reasonably answered here on Stackoverflow. Also the support of `docuemnt.execCommand()` varies across browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html

Comment: Have you found an answer for this? im searching for the same thing!

Comment: @alecellis1985 Yes i got the answer. See the accepted mark answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is work for me. So try this may be it will be also helpful for you.(single and multiple node).

```
 <script>
       var selectedElement = null;

        function singleline() {
            document.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'p')
            var selectedNodes = [];
            var sel = rangy.getSelection();
            for (var i = 0; i < sel.rangeCount; i++) {
                selectedNodes = selectedNodes.concat(sel.getRangeAt(i).getNodes());
                $(selectedNodes).css("height", "20px");       
            }
            selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
            $(selectedElement).css("height", "20px");              
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: Anyone tried this with Internet Explorer? Docs says this on `formatblock`: “Internet Explorer supports only heading tags H1 - H6, ADDRESS, and PRE” https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<select id="lineHeight" onchange="changeLineHeight(this)">
<option value="20px">20px</option>
<option value="80px">80px</option>
<option value="100px">100px</option>
<option value="200px">200px</option>
</select>
<button id="bold" onclick="doThis()">Bold</button>

<div id="textcontent" contenteditable ="true" STYLE="height:300px; background-color:white; overflow:auto; width:100%;">

</div>
<script>
    function changeLineHeight(sel) {
        var t = document.getElementById('textcontent');
        t.style.lineHeight = sel.value;
    }
</script>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/niwumifo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is works fine for whole div. But my problem is- i want to change line height of each line separately. is it possible?